# Can I have a database less blog with October CMS?

Tags: blogs, octobercms, flat-file

I would like to know if is possible to get a blog without a database, which is a typical static site generator functionality, with October cms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, an OctoberCMS plugin would allow you to do this.

The free Blog plugin by RainLab uses a database though.

The default setup of OctoberCMS uses static pages for it's site content also (static being files and not a database). OctoberCMS won 2018's Best Flat File CMS by CMS critic.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, but you didn't respond to my question. I know that with a plugin I can have a blog within October CMS, but as you put, it will require a database. My question is about the possibility of a blog on October WITHOUT a database, as the SSG's do.

Comment: No, as I stated: "Sure, an OctoberCMS plugin would allow you to do this." (Flat file).

I only stated that "The free Blog plugin by RainLab uses a database **though**." (notice that the most popular blog plugin does use a database).

Comment: So to be absolutely clear: Yes, you can create a plugin for OctoberCMS without a database.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can! [Follow This](https://octobercms.com/support/article/ob-13)

Then you can create your cms pages as posts. I believe there is a plugin to turn the editor into a wysiwyg which would speed the process of making blog posts.

Comment: Ok, I saw this video and explanation. But as I understand, the "generator" component of an SSG it's responsible to automatically as I publish a new blog post, show it on the main recent posts page, also on the category and/or tags it belongs and etc.. With the page you redirected me, I will have to manually put the published post on the blog main page and on it's respective category. Is that it? I want to make sure I understand well.

Comment: Sure because you are using OctoberCMS in a limited way you will have to do a bit of extra work. I am sure you can automate the process of fetching the cms pages then turning them into a list like a normal blog would look like.